# Angular file download with name from content Content-Disposition

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to download generated xls file using angular and set the file name according response header Content-Disposition.

I use something like

```
downloadFile(): Observable<any> {
  var url= "http://somehting";
  return this.http.get(url, { observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob' as 'json' });  
}
```

and later in my controller:

```
this.dataService.downloadFile().subscribe(
    data => {
        this.debug.msg("response:", JSON.stringify(data));
        saveAs(data.body, "test.xlsx");
    },
    err => {
        console.error(err);
        alert("Problem while downloading the file.\n" + "[" + err.status + "] " + err.statusText);
    }
);
```

unfortunately the response headers are not set and the body is also empty.

```
response: {
   "headers":{
      "normalizedNames":{

      },
      "lazyUpdate":null
   },
   "status":200,
   "statusText":"OK",
   "url":"http://localhost:4200/MyEndpoint/GetDownload",
   "ok":true,
   "type":4,
   "body":{

   }
}
```

if I change procedure to be responseType: blob, then I am able to get the content of the file but I don't know how to get to `response.headers`. 
did I miss something and if it's the case what is it?

Answer (score 5):

Based on other stack overflow posts...this works for me

on the server set header

```
Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "content-disposition");
```

angular dataService definition of the download procedure. Important is to set observable to HttpResponse

```
  downloadFile(): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>> {

    var url =  "http://host/GetDownload";

    return this.http.get<Blob>(url, { observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob' as 'json' });
  }
```

and controller

```
 this.dataService.downloadFile().subscribe(
      data => {

        var fileName = "report.xlsx";
        const contentDisposition = data.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
        if (contentDisposition) {
          const fileNameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
          const matches = fileNameRegex.exec(contentDisposition);
          if (matches != null && matches[1]) {
            fileName = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
          }
        }

        saveAs(data.body, fileName);
      },
      err => {
        console.error(err);
        this.blockUI.stop();
        alert("Problem while downloading the file.\n"+
            "["+err.status+"] "+err.statusText);
      });
}
```

Comment: hi! tell me please what doing saveAs function?

Comment: from what I seen the saveAs function is a lib for download files.

Comment: import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
-  https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/